# django how to show images from my user directory

Tags: django

I am using linux and created a Django project.

I  have folder in my home directory /home/simha/siteimages

i am trying to show a list of images from the above directory

In views.py

```
def gallery(request):
    path="/home/simha/siteimages"
    img_list =os.listdir(path)
    return render(request,'blog/gallery.html', {'images': img_list})
```

gallery.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% for image in images %}
<img src='/static/{{image}}' />
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Its not working.

It says at `img_list =os.listdir(path)` error `No such file or directory`

Comment: Are you sure the folder exists? i.e) go to siteimages & `pwd`

Comment: the folder exists.

Comment: Is the `siteimages` folder your static root?, if not then it wouldn't work anyway

Comment: If the folder exist then listdir will give you the list of files. So I suspect still you are passing the wrong path... please give the correct path what `pwd` gave..

Comment: Does your Django-process have access to read your home directory?